# Client Credentials access token not working office 365

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am using client credentials flow to generate an access token. Following is the request.

[image: Using client credentials flow]

I received the access token and I am using to call Web API like

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders/inbox/messages
```

Following is the screenshot
[image: Calling Web API]

Calling Web API gives `InvalidAuthenticationToken` Error.

Any workaround on this.?

Answer (score 1):

You're `resource` should be set to `https://graph.microsoft.com`.

In your screenshot, the`resource` is set to `https://outlook.office.com` but you're calling a Microsoft Graph. Since you're providing an `access_token` for a different resource, Microsoft Graph is rejecting it.

You also need to make sure you've requested the proper Microsoft Graph permissions in the Azure Portal. To call [`/mailFolders/inbox/messages`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/mailfolder_list_messages) for example, you need request permission for either `Mail.Read` or `Mail.ReadWrite`.

Finally, you cannot use `/me` with the Client Credentials grant. The `/me` is simply shorthand for `/users/{current-user-id}/`. Since Client Credentials does not *have* a current user, the API has no idea which user `me` is. You will need to reference a specific `user` entity in the path:

```
/v1.0/users/{userPrincipalName}/mailfolders/inbox/messages
```